# Can we integrate mailchimp with Google site

Tags: php, html, mailchimp, google-sites

I am creating site on Google site , I want to know can we integrate Mailchimp with Google site.
I saw the official mail chimp integration [link](http://mailchimp.com/features/integrations/) 
It says you can integrate with

- Google Ananlytic
- Google Doc
- Google Contacts

Can somebody tell me either it is possible or not?
Thanks
**NOTE: I am tagging PHP and HTML as these gurus may encounter the same issue.**

Comment: This is the type of thing that [I do](https://www.pipethru.com). How exactly are you trying to connect Google site with mailchimp? Are you sending a signup form to a campaign? Manage templates or campaigns through your site?

Comment: subscribing feature for the user.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to subscribe users to mailchimp campaigns, and the integration you need is pulling subscribers from Google contacts?

Answer (score 2):

See this site hope it works for you, this is the [link](https://www.itduzzit.com/connect/mailchimp-to-google-sites)
it connects mailchimp to google sites using [itDuzzit](https://www.itduzzit.com/)

Comment: Yes but this is not free @Anurag

Comment: This site no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sites click the `<HTML>` button and paste the HTML code you get from Mailchimp. You get that by going to the Mailchimp list you want people to subscribe to, in the navbar click "For your Website" > "Signup Form Embed Code" and use the code at the bottom.

Comment: This have actually worked.

Comment: Google Sites no longer lets users do this.